# how to make a function for naming variable when execute pdo prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Question is : Is it posible to make a function that can handle naming the variable, so i dont need to describe one by one the varibel in `$stmt->execute(array());`. what variable i mean is example :

```
:categoryId=> $categoryId;
```

MyProject :

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO category (categoryName, categorySort) VALUES (:categoryName, :categorySort)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':categoryName' => $categoryName,
                ':categorySort' => $categorySort,
                ));
```

Here is Fucntion from [Akintunde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7104527/akintunde) that i already change:

```
    function doSave($array, $table) {
if (count($array) == 0) {
    throw new Exception('Array cant be empty');
} else {
    //prepare the query first
    $prepare_1 = 'INSERT INTO' . '`' . $table . '`'; //start preparing
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $columns[] = ':' . $key . ','; //gets all columns and add commas
    }
    //now you can combine everything and prepare
    $connect->prepare($prepare_1 . ')(VALUES(' . $columns . ')'); //remember to add the values. also test this section as its not tested
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $connect->bindParam(':' . $key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $connect->execute();
}
}
```

And for use it :

```
$array = array('categoryName' => ':categoryName', 'categorySort' => 'categorySort');
$connect->doSave($array, 'category');
```

And here error i got :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::doSave() in C:\xampp\htdocs\program\admin\add-category.php on line 38
```

What i forget to change or what is missing ?

Thanks please remind me if the question not clear.

Comment: No, the question is not clear.

Comment: Is it posible to simplify when execute the prepared statement i dont need to describe one by one the values

Comment: you can have like a generic function. In that function, you pass the array and then use a foreach loop. Therefore your binded variables would be your `key`

Comment: can you give an example please ?

Comment: I recommend you use a framework like laravel's eloquent. It might give you the stone to kill a million birds at once.

Comment: thanks but i still want to study without framework first